# How can I persist state variables at two levels in python?

Tags: python, scheme, state, sicp, mutation

There is this code in scheme (from the old SICP course of berkeley) which makes a counter function that persists local state variables at two levels, similar to class variables and instance variables.

```
  (define make-count
    (let ((glob 0))
     (lambda ()
      (let ((loc 0))
        (lambda ()
          (set! loc (+ loc 1))
          (set! glob (+ glob 1))
          (list loc glob))))))

(define c1 (make-count))
(define c2 (make-count))
(c1)   ; (1 1)
(c1)   ; (2 2) 
(c2)   ; (1 3)
(c2)   ; (2 4)
```

I could not find a way to resemble this functionality in python. As an example I wrote this code which does the wrong thing:

```
def make_counter():
  glob = 0
  def a():
    loc = 0
    def b():
        nonlocal glob, loc
        loc += 1
        glob += 1
        return [loc, glob]
    return b
  return a()

c1 = make_counter()
c2 = make_counter()
c1()  # [1, 1]
c1()  # [2, 2]
c2()  # [1, 1]
c2()  # [2, 2]
```

I know there is no 'let' functionality in python but,
What do I do wrong.
Does the enviornment model in python differ from that of scheme?

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with Scheme, what do you want `make_counter` to do in this example?

Comment: @Kemp A counter that is created by make_counter is supposed to increment its own local variable (loc) and the global variable (glob) for all counters and return them.

Comment: Possibly you want to make glob a global variable then? Define it outside of the `make_counter` function and pull it in using `global glob` at the start of the function. Another way, in a different coding style, would be to wrap it up in a Counter class that has a static member variable that each instance can increment. Do either of those sound reasonable?

Comment: @Kemp. Yes they do, but I don't want glob to be global and also don't want to leverage python object system. I just want to use functions and closures.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to find an answer to the question. I translated the code to python as close as I could, but am still confused about how it works.

Any explanation would be appriciated.

```
def make_counter_helper():
    glob = 0
    def a():
        loc = 0
        def counter():
            nonlocal loc, glob
            glob += 1
            loc += 1
            return [loc, glob]
        return counter
    return a

make_counter = make_counter_helper()

c1 = make_counter()
c2 = make_counter()
c1()  # [1, 1]
c1()  # [2, 2]
c2()  # [1, 3]
c2()  # [2, 4]
```

Comment: The lisp version uses `let` wrapped around the outermost function to introduce a new, anonymous scope shared by all invocations. You could use the global scope, which you have reasonably rejected. Or you could use an explicit scope with classes to restrict the "global" variable to a single class. Or you can do as you've done, and use a lambda to create an implicit scope. Any of these will work. Your attempt in the question did not work because there was no scope shared by all invocations of the `make_counter` function.

Comment: @amalloy In the Question, each call to make_counter creates a different environment in which "glob" is initially set to zero, As in this answer, each call to make counter creates a new environment, for each the parent environment is the same